# Cannot edit AlertTones folder in OSX Big Sur

Tags: macos, permissions, macos-big-sur

I am trying to get custom alert tones on mac and am in the alert tones folder (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AlertTones) however I do not have permission to edit, copy or paste into this folder.
I have disabled SIP and this does not work.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This directory is part of the read-only filesystem in Big Sur.

Technically, you can mount the system as writable in Recovery mode, but you will lose FileVault encryption in the process.  Future updates will wipe out your work.  Not recommended.  Please see the warnings and disclaimers outlined in the link below.

Proceed at your own risk, as described in the accepted answer here: [Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur)

Comment: My apologies, I don't completely understand what you are saying. What is filevault encryption and would I be able to get it back? I do not want to have problems in future updates so if that's the case maybe I won't follow through with this.

Comment: FileVault is the full-disk encryption used to secure your MacBook startup disk, details are [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837) ..  I would recommend against trying any of this.